# Use first relationship in query path to filter the rest of the path relationships - Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I havent been able to find this question. I have the following graph

```
A-[x]->B
B-[y]->C
B-[x]->C
C-[y]->F
C-[x]->D
```

I want to match A-[x]->B-[x]->C  but use the relationship name 'x' found in the 1st part of the query 
A-[x]->B in the B-[x]->C part of the query. I have relationship types that are randomly assigned, so I need to construct a query that is non-specific with the relationship type, but that can use the first matched relationship as the relationship type for the rest of the path.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot parameterise the type of the relationship so the query has to be a little more complicated.

You can start with something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Node)-[r]-(b:Node)
WITH a, r, TYPE(r) AS type, b
MATCH path=b-[rr*]-c
WHERE ALL (rrtype IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) 
       WHERE type = TYPE(rrtype))
RETURN a, r, path
```

This query matches your relationship from `a` to `b` and uses a `WITH` operator to carry forward the type of the initial relationship. It then matches all the possible paths from `b` to `c`. Finally the `WHERE ALL` clause filters out any paths where the types of the *all* of the relationships do not match the original relationship type.

This is going to be expensive as everything is unconstrained, so add some labels and relationship types where possible (and obviously add your initial matching code for `a`,`b` and `c`).

Comment: John Mark, thank you ! Did you mean :  WHERE ALL (rrtype IN RELATIONSHIPS(path)  and not  WHERE ALL (rrtype IN RELATIONSHIPS(p)  ?  I dont see 'p' defined